# How to map this link table in cf-orm?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, hbmxml

A 1---* A_B *---1 B

Table A has aID (PK), Table B has bID (PK), 
table A_B has:

aID (PK, FK),
bID (PK, FK),
num

I tried

```
property name="A" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="A" fkcolumn="aID";
property name="B" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="B" fkcolumn="bID";
property name="num" type="numeric";
```

but CF keep asking me for an ID column... what can I do?  The FK's should be the PK's.

If there's no way to specify it in CFC, how to represent this link table in hbm xml?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently no hbmxml is needed! Awesome...

```
property name="A" fieldtype="id,many-to-one" cfc="A" fkcolumn="aID";
property name="B" fieldtype="id,many-to-one" cfc="B" fkcolumn="bID";
property name="num" type="numeric";
```

Thanks to Brian Kotek's answer at: http://groups.google.com/group/cf-orm-dev/msg/a6ccc2194fceb930

Answer (score 1):

Can you alter the table so that it has a unique, auto generated id?  Primary keys should be unique and never change. (part of a link mapping keys could technically change)  Also it is best to have a surrogate key instead of composite keys since you can unique identify a record by a primary key instead of composite columns.

I use Hibernate and all my link tables have their own surrogate primary keys.  Otherwise you will have to deal with the [composite id mapping declaration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid).

Comment: I think composite ID wouldn't work since the IDs in my case are FK's in a many-to-one relationship, right?

Comment: Yes, I can use an additional ID, but I prefer composite ID, thx

Comment: composite ID would work.  It doesn't matter if they are FKs.  But relying on composite keys makes things more difficult like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the fkcolumn for property="Bs" should be "bID".

```
property name="Bs" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="B" fkcolumn="bID";
```

The other thing I noticed from your schema is I believe the link table really has a many-to-one  as there are many items in the link table which link to one item in the A table and B table.  Try switching to a "many-to-one" and see if that helps.

Comment: thx, updated, but the problem is.. the ID property is required but can't define it since fieldtype can't be "id" and "many-to-one"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a composite id, couldn't really find a very good example, but here are a two references;

http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=47723
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid